# Blackberry list field without canvas

Tags: blackberry, canvas, listfield, browserfield

Is it possible to create a customized list field in BB, where each row will have 4 different labels, and a bitmap field, without implementing the drawListRow method?

Since drawListRow uses canvas I want to avoid it. Because, I need to display a browser field in list row. Or is it possible to add label fields in list row?

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't going to be able to implement this the way you want - try putting more than one BrowserField on a screen at once and you'll soon run into multiple issues. I'd suggest creating a custom Field to act as a row instead, or try and get the desired look n feel using Field Managers.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, you are right, more than 1 browser fields, do create a problem. Is there a way, to wrap text, for list row, in the method drawListRow(), where we have to use the paint object.

Comment: You need to implement your own text wrapping logic.